# React Native Pass JSON into a var

Tags: react-native

I just started programming with react-nativ and I can't find a solution for the following problem:

I am trying to create a list of markers that are visible on my map. And I'm struggling to pass the JSON I get from the getMapBoundaries function into a variable.
The JSON looks like this:

Object {
"northEast": object {
"latitude": 213.734743474374773,
"longitude": 125.43054545432234,
},
"southwest": object {
"latitude": 133.77309210624907,
"longitude": 122.085854880802145,
}

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a JSON-string from getMapBoundaries you can use it like:

```js
var jsonString = getMapBoundaries();
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```